# dotnet core Google Cloud Function with Firebase Admin SDK

Tags: c#, .net-core, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-authentication, google-cloud-functions

I have a Flutter client app that authorises the user using Google Provider.  I want to use the dotnet core C# Google Cloud function to read the authorisation token and read the FireStore using Firebase Admin SDK.  The documentation for this is scant and/or written for other languages.

Anyone have any examples or links to dotnet core documentation to do this as I've spent all day trying to figure this out?

I've got a simple function as per: https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/quickstart-dotnet#whats-next

and I see some tests that give a clue to how some of the SDK works:  https://github.com/firebase/firebase-admin-dotnet/blob/f6babbd4e59655f01be4a43230b5be198fc4f8cd/FirebaseAdmin/FirebaseAdmin.Snippets/FirebaseAuthSnippets.cs#L608-L629

```
using Google.Cloud.Functions.Framework;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using FirebaseAdmin;
using FirebaseAdmin.Auth;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;
using Google.Apis.Auth.OAuth2;

namespace HelloHttpFunction
{
public class Function : IHttpFunction
{

    private readonly ILogger _logger;
    public Function(ILogger<Function> logger) =>
     _logger = logger;

 //how to use firebase auth to check token and get uid from calling client
 //how to read a set of docs from firestore
 //already setup the Google environment variables

    public async Task HandleAsync(HttpContext context)
    {
        HttpRequest request = context.Request;


        // this my all guesswork below:
        FirebaseApp.Create(new AppOptions()
        {
            Credential = GoogleCredential.GetApplicationDefault(),
        });

        FirebaseToken decodedToken = await FirebaseAuth.DefaultInstance.VerifyIdTokenAsync(idToken);
        string uid = decodedToken.Uid;
        var user = FirebaseAuth.DefaultInstance.GetUserAsync(uid);

        await context.Response.WriteAsync("Hello, Functions Framework. ");
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Any chance you found a solution for this? :)

Comment: No I gave up.  Might revisit in couple of months as I'm still doing other codign work

Comment: Well. Might have something working really soon. Last night I got my react app to authenticate and then call my AspNetCore WebAPI with token and validate it. Next step is to call the Firebase API to test it works too. If I get it up and running I will share result here :) Just not entirely sure when I will get the time. This weekend is entirely booked.

Answer (score 0):

if what you are wanting to know is how to obtain idToken, it is in the context. You have to extract it from the request headers.